# Best or all Methods to validating an XML against XSD schema using C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2013, xsd-validation

Which method exist in C# to validate an XML against XSD Schema using C# ?

One of this is using System.Xml, using System.Linq.

Which other validate methods exist?

I look for the methods to derive examine the methods and use.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try validating using LINQ statements?

[How to: Validate Using XSD (LINQ to XML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have various options to deal with this

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3740e0b5(v=vs.110).aspx
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10444/Simple-code-to-validate-an-XML-file-
   against-a-sche
4. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/validating-an-xml-document-programmatically/

Please go through the above links.

Comment: thank you Joseph. I know all this pages. What i want is the list of all Methods...